# Changing from JFrame to JApplet

Tags: java, swing, deployment, jframe, japplet

I'm trying to change some Java applications that I made using JFrame to JApplets so they can be placed on a website that I am also trying to make. I am just wondering what needs to be changed in my programs to accomplish this. Here is an example of one of the programs (I tried to run this one with just changing the extension and some attributes, but it just disappears with the process still running):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener; 
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Snake extends JApplet//extends JFrame
{
    private Panel panel;
    Dimension x = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    private final int SCALER = 25, LENGTH = (int) x.getWidth()/SCALER-1, 
                      HEIGHT = (int) x.getHeight()/SCALER-1;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Snake();
}

public Snake()
{
    //setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(x);
    //setTitle("SNAKE");
    //setResizable(false);
    panel = new Panel(20,20,SCALER);
    add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    addKeyListener(handler);
    setVisible(true);
}

private class Handler implements KeyListener
{
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        switch (e.getKeyCode())
        {
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            panel.pass(270);
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            panel.pass(90);
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            panel.pass(0);
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            panel.pass(180);        
            break;
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
    {

    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
    {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Put everything in a JPanel instead, then you can put the JPanel in a JFrame or a JApplet without changing anything about your program.

Comment: I sort of have that set up already though. The panel that I add is actually a class that extends JPanel and has the majority of the code. This class was just the JFrame at first with keyListeners for inputs. The thing that I'm really trying to understand is that the program will run with music but I cannot see it at all under the JApplet extension.

Comment: *"I'm trying to change some Java applications that I made using JFrame to JApplets so they can be placed on a website.."*  Don't waste your time(1).  A frame can be launched direct from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  1) And by 'time' I meant both in the conversion process, as well as the eternal maintenance required for applets.

Answer (score 0):

With this code, you have both versions (JFrame and JApplet)

```
public class Snake extends JApplet 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // JFrame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Snake");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Applet
        JApplet applet = new Snake();
        applet.init();

        // Insert the Applet into JFrame
        frame.getContentPane().add(applet);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
...
```